# how do you include a csrf token when testing a POST endpoint in django?

Tags: python, django, testing, csrf

I am learning how to make an api endpoint and I am trying to write a test to see if a post request returns a 200 status code. I plan on writing more tests to see if the endpoint is returning all the expected results as well.  I keep getting a 403 status code and I think it is because I need to include a csrf token in the post data. What is a good way to test a POST endpoint in django?

my Test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app import settings
import requests

class ProjectEndpoint(TestCase):
   def post_endpoint(self):
      data = {'hello':'23'}
      post_project = requests.post(settings.BASE_URL+'/api/project', params=data)
      self.assertEqual(post_endpoint.status_code, 200)
```

This test keeps failing with 403 != 200

I think it is because the view is protected against csrf attacks, but I am really not sure. Appreciate any insight that someone has.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Actually, django doesn't enforce (by default) csrf checking with tests, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#testing:

> The CsrfViewMiddleware will usually be a big hindrance to testing view
>   functions, due to the need for the CSRF token which must be sent with
>   every POST request. For this reason, Django’s HTTP client for tests
>   has been modified to set a flag on requests which relaxes the
>   middleware and the csrf_protect decorator so that they no longer
>   rejects requests. In every other respect (e.g. sending cookies etc.),
>   they behave the same.
>
> If, for some reason, you want the test client to perform CSRF checks,
>   you can create an instance of the test client that enforces CSRF
>   checks:
>
> > > > from django.test import Client
> > > >
> > > > csrf_client = Client(enforce_csrf_checks=True)

However, this does require you to be using the Django Client vs requests; as far as I know, Django doesn't mock/instrument/etc. requests... so you're actually hitting the real server when you run that unit test.

Also note that you should name your test functions something that starts with test_

So something like this (when run through django manage.py test .ProjectEndpoint)

```
def test_post_endpoint(self):
   data = {'hello':'23'}
   c = Client() #above, from django.test import TestCase,Client
   #optional, but may be necessary for your configuration: c.login("username","password")
   response = c.post('/api/project',params=data)
   self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```